# How to google authenticate a user from next js frontend to node js backend

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, passport.js

I have set up Google authentication using passport js in my node js backend. I am also storing them in my MySQL database. the backend is complete and running on port 3001.
Now I want to create a login page and let people authenticate in my next js frontend. but I don't know how to do that. should I just call the Google auth callback URL from the frontend?
I have searched for an hour but I didn't find anything. I saw everyone is using nextAuth. but I want to use node js as the backend, not next js.

Answer (score 0):

After completing the auth you have to save it as JWT in cookies:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, SECRET_KEY);
```

In client you can decode JWT with NO access to `SECRET_KEY` with this method (we do not pass `SECRET_KEY` because of security reasons):

```
const decoded = jwt.decode(token)
```

But if you want to decode JWT with `SECRET_KEY`, you have to pass JWT to backend and decode it, if decode is true, redirect user to other page like `dashboard` and if it makes error, delete JWT cookie and redirect user to `login` page.

```
jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY, function(err, decoded) {
    if(err){
        //delete JWT cookie
        //redirect to login page
    }

    if(decoded){
        //make JWT token or redirect user to other page
    }
});
```

You can read more about this lib in here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and answer. I am not looking for this. I wanted to know how can I make a request to my backend Google authentication callback. I found that ```window.open(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/auth/google`, "_self");``` this is a way to do that. I implemented it and it saved cookies in my browser. it is working. but do you know any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm glad that your problem was solved. You can use node `fetch` or `axios` to make a request to your API. This will save cookie also